# Change Mapped table dynamically in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. In my DB, I have a table (DOCMASTER) which is mapped in my model, and on occasion, has a backup from a different date created (e.g. DOCMASTER_10_01_2015). The mappings are identical, with the exception of the keys/constraints. These are not brought over with the backup.

I have an application with a dropdown that is filled with all of the tables in the DB that are of type "DOCMASTER". The user selects which table they would like to query from, and they search for a client in that particular version of the table.

What I would ideally like to do is remap my model to use the selected table instead of the mapped table, however when I do that using DbModelBuilder, it seems to want to remap all of the tables in that model, not just the one table. I receive the error "CodeFirstNamespace.CUSTOM1: : EntityType 'CUSTOM1' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType" wherein 'CUSTOM1' is my table name, but I receive this for all of my tables in the model.

I am debating just using a paramaterized query to query the selected table directly. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: this may be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30201242/1236044

Comment: Have you thought about using just one table in conjunction with data partitioning? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx

Comment: I do not have control of the database, so using one table is not an option. I ended up just building a paramaterized query and pulling the data in that way. This is for an internal app, so it is good enough this way.