# Bind one class to multiple tables Based on Parameter EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api

I have an old application build using asp.net web forms I'm trying to use the existing database with new application using API2 
the problem was application creates new tables for each client registered on the system

> ex: 16_Notifications, 17_Notifications,18-....

How to bind Notification Class shown below to one table based on the logged in user

assume have the Id from WebApi as parameter let's say

> string Id = 16;

Can I do something like below ?

```
Table[Id+"_Notifications"]
public class Notification{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Notification {get;set;}
}
```

where 16,17 from the logged in user

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30201242/1236044

Comment: Please explain how creating a different context for each of these helped? Doesn't seem to make sense to me. Why not just flatten the data going forward? so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Viewing post here [Implement IDbModelCacheKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095663/emit-dbcontext-onmodelcreating-on-every-context-creation/30201242#30201242)

hope this help someone else for me finally make it's work by changing this line

> base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RepositoryConnectionString"] 
>    + "; Extended Properties=\"setElementsTableId=" + setElementsTableId + "\"")

to using Application Name instead of Extended Properties

> base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RepositoryConnectionString"] + " ; Application Name ='setElementsTableId=" + setElementsTableId + "\'")

in the mentioned post

Comment: I don't get it... why create a different context for this?

Comment: @Seabizkit create different context so the onCreating method call every time i change the connection string

Comment: Sozs still don't get it and i've been working with this tech for quite some time and consider myself well versed. So you have many contexts... or just wen changing con string, wouldn't that get really annoying or are you doing something dynamically. I get you have tables with number appended..but why not just have one context with all of them manually set. How often do you add new ones? what is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: maybe if you check this link thinks will be more clear http://stackoverflow.com/a/30201242/1236044 ;
i can't do this manually cause i don't know the actual number of the tables and all tables have the same structure , I use one context but change the connection string to force onCreating method to be run and initialize loged in user tables by map class to specified table

Comment: add table from another applications and i don't need this application to change database structure so i turn of migrations features

Comment: Mmm i think i follow, but this would only work for if you had 1 table in your context right? which is a very odd design